# How to get checkbox values when checked in angular5

Tags: angular

Can anyone please help, I am trying to get checked names when checkbox checked. Here my requirement is i dont want to display my checkboxes in forloop. I tried oneway, but i feel this is not Correct way. The link is shown in below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gv2vkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

What i have tried here **splice is not working**. Can anyone please help is there any another easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the following, which the function is a one-liner and pretty straight forward. Just pass the target value to your function, and then either add or remove the value, based on if it is in the array already or not:

```html
<label class="contain">Node
  <input type="checkbox" value="node" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
</label>        
<label class="contain">Angular
  <input type="checkbox" value="angular" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
</label>
<label class="contain">PHP
  <input type="checkbox" value="php" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Then the `onChange` function:

```ts
onChange(value) {
  this.Course.includes(value) ? this.Course.splice(this.Course.indexOf(value), 1) 
                                : this.Course.push(value)
}
```

Comment: Here you mentioned--->this.course.includes...., Where you use course. Directly you are firing an event from html. I used course after firing an event, that event i stores in this.course.

Comment: @PRUDHVIRAJ Sorry, I don't completely understand your question... do you mean that you don't know what `course` is. Sorry, I used `course`, instead of `Course`, which you are using. Here's a stackblitz for demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cprxp9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Compared to other answers this is the best for me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please, not use (change), use "Angular Way". That's: think in view-model.

```
  <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="variable"/>
```

As you has severals "items", you can use an array, so you has

```
  <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="variable[0]"/>
  <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="variable[1]"/>
```

Don't forget declare in .ts

```
  variable:boolean[]=[];
```

Your function "submit" take account of the array and show the values

```
submit()
{
   let result:string="";
   if (variable[0])
      result+=",Node"
   if (variable[1])
      result+=",Angular"
   ...
   result=result.substr(1);
}
```

Other way of the submit is

```
  submit() {
    const values = ['Node', 'Angular', 'Php']
    let result = "";
    values.forEach((x, index) => {
      if (this.variable[index])
        result += "," + x;
    })
    result = result.substr(1);
    console.log(result)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get only check value like true and false . You can use  (change)="onChange($event)" event for fire an event on checkBox.

Comment: This is only I tried please give a look on the above link.